# How to get the URL of the account logo which is used by default?

Tags: apex, community, account, js

[image]
[image]

The first pic is the default logo suggested by salesforce and on the second pic is the url, and I want to get this url by using Apex or JS. THanks

Answer (score 1):

In [documentation](http://Salesforce%20uses%20the%20company%E2%80%99s%20website%20to%20locate%20the%20company%20logo.) on enabling account logos, following is mentioned.

> Salesforce uses the company’s website to locate the company logo.

Logos are not stored in your org but are retrieved at runtime by Salesforce using some internal service based on value of `website` field. I'm afraid, you won't be able to retrieve logo easy way.

If you really really have to show the logos, there are external services like [clearbit](https://clearbit.com/logo) which provides logo when you pass company name.

Hope this helps.